# creating new column in r based on a value every cycle of 10

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

New to R and computer science so help appreciated

Trying to figure out how to create a new column (y) in a data frame that corresponds to the value of (x), every value of 10 in x should given to a new y. Quite difficult to explain, don't know where to start either with a loop or if statement. For Example current data set

```
 event_id   x
      1     0
      2     2
      3     5
      4     11
      5     12 
      6     17
      7     25
      8     28
      9     30
      10    34
```

but I want it to look like this

```
 event_id   x    y
      1     0    1
      2     2    1
      3     5    1
      4     11   2
      5     12   2
      6     17   2
      7     25   3
      8     28   3 
      9     30   3
      10    34   4
```

Hope this makes sense as the first 3 values are all < 10 so are given a value of 1, but then this repeats as the next 3 values are between 10-20 so y is 2 etc.

Comment: You have 0 -> 1 and 30 ->3 in your expected output.  These seem slightly incompatible.  Can you clarify expected behaviour for x=10 (ie y should be 1 or 2?), and for x=20...  And whether you definitely want x=0 to break this pattern, or should x=0 give y=0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$y <- with(
  df, 
  findInterval(x, seq(0, max(x) + 10, by = 10))
)

df
   event_id  x y
1         1  0 1
2         2  2 1
3         3  5 1
4         4 11 2
5         5 12 2
6         6 17 2
7         7 25 3
8         8 28 3
9         9 30 4
10       10 34 4
```

This assumes 30 should be mapped 4, just as 0 is mapped to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df$y = df$x %/% 10 + 1
```

Comment: `df$x %/% 11 + 1
`

Comment: @PoGibas - No, `%/% 11` is not correct.  Try `120 %/% 11 + 1` for example, or `c(21,22) %/% 11 + 1`  and you will see that this does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
df$y <- floor(df$x / 10.1) + 1
```

matches OP request:

```
#   event_id  x y
#1         1  0 1
#2         2  2 1
#3         3  5 1
#4         4 11 2
#5         5 12 2
#6         6 17 2
#7         7 25 3
#8         8 28 3
#9         9 30 3
#10       10 34 4
```